# Modelling a smoothly curved ramp between two edges

Tags: modeling, objects, bezier-curves

I have a shape that I made out of extruding a circle a few times and adjusting the size of the edges.

I'd like to make it so that the highlighted edges form a smooth ramp, but I'm not sure how to do this. I've tried bevels, but it's beveling the vertical edges only, without making any kind of curve

[image]

This is roughly the shape I'd like to achieve

[image]

What are some ways of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create this shape:

[image]

Then bevel the bottom edge, tweak the parameters in the *Operator* box so that it follows the curve with the amount of segments you want:

[image]

Or just create this cylinder shape, create horizontal edge loops:

[image]

then scale the edge loops so that it fits the shape, create additional ones:

[image]

Comment: If you use Proportional Edit  set to Sphere, you can select an edge loop just above the centre and scale with SHIFT-Z to create the curve.

Comment: @John Eason oh ok I haven't tried